# Any ideas where on the internet I can just post thoughts on books I read?

Tags: discussion

Any ideas where on the internet I can just post thoughts on books I read? I don't think stackexchange is right, even if you phrase it as a question. I don't personally know anyone I can share my thoughts on anything with, and I don't want an audience (CF social media), just a discussion or platform (of my reading).

Comment: This question is not within scope of Phil Meta. Just create a blog. If you don't want audience, don't click on Publish when you're done with your draft.

Comment: ok i guess that makes sense @IñakiViggers

Comment: Reddit is a good sounding board